# angular-file-upload with Amazon S3 getting 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular-file-upload, ng-file-upload

I have an amazon s3 endpoint that I'm trying to upload files to on the client side (with some back-end help).

Here's my policy code:

```js
s3Policy = JSON.stringify({
  expiration: '2038-12-01T12:00:00.000Z',
  conditions: [
    ["starts-with", "$key", filename], 
    { "bucket": bucket }, 
    { "acl": "public-read" },
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", (fileType || 'application/octet-stream')]
  ]
})
```

(I encode it into base64 after this)

Here's my angular request:

```js
  var nameData = findExtension(file.name);
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/project/' + projectId + '/files/gets3authorization',
    data: {
      fileType: file.type,
      fileExtension: nameData.extension
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    var s3Data = response.data;
    Upload.upload({
      url: s3Data.bucketURL,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        key: s3Data.savedFileName,
        acl: 'public-read',
        "Content-Type": (file.type || 'application/octet-stream'),
        AWSAccessKeyId: s3Data.key,
        headers: { Authorization: undefined },
        Policy: s3Data.s3Policy,
        Signature: s3Data.s3Signature,
        filename: s3Data.savedFileName + '.' + nameData.extension,
        file: file
      }
    }).progress(function(evt) {
      var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
      $scope.log = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' +
        evt.config.data.file.name + '\n' + $scope.log;
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.log = 'file: ' + config.data.file.name + ', Response: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n' + $scope.log;
      });
    }).error(function(err) {
      console.log("inner err: ", err)
    })
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('outer err: ', error);
  });
```

Here's what my policy looks like (I'm going to tighten security once POSTs start working):

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "FileUpload",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/files*"
  }]
}
```

Here's my CORS config (again, will tighten security later):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

[And here's response from chrome tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqdLD.png)

In the `Response Headers` it includes `POST`, but the `Allow` doesn't include it.

Any help is very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You can't send `POST` requests directly to your web site that is hosted in S3, because the web site endpoints don't accept them.  You have to send `POST` requests to the REST endpoint for your bucket; for non-HTTPS, the hostname `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` should always work.  For HTTPS, different region-specific permutations are required.

Comment: With that change, I'm getting this error after the POST: `Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$bucket", "stub-19.s3.amazonaws.com"]`.  My signature bucket and angular POST bucket are both defined as `[BUCKET].s3.amazonaws.com`.  I'm ignoring the `/files` portion just to get the main functionality working

Comment: Remove `.s3.amazonaws.com` from the bucket name inside the post policy.

Comment: Awesome--it worked!  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

When hosting a web site using S3's [static web site hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) feature, you can use the form `POST` [browser-based upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html) feature; however, the web site endpoint doesn't accept the `POST` request, and will respond with `405 Method Not Allowed`.  This is not a permissions or CORS issue.

`POST` requests are only accepted by the REST endpoints.  For non-HTTPS requests, the pattern `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` will route to the the specific bucket's endpoint (but the bucket name in the signed policy document remains `bucket-name` only, without the full domain name).

For https requests where the target bucket name has a one or more dots in it, you'll need to use a path-style URL for the REST endpoint, which is `https://s3[-region].amazonaws.com/bucket-name/` (otherwise the hostname won't match the wildcard SSL certificate).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region